# Calculate ellipse eccentricity using dplyr from ellipse points in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, ellipse

I'm trying to calculate the eccentricity of ellipses contained in the following file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cqwghg7uvj1xl4d/ellipses.csv?dl=0

It's organized as 100 points that define 100 ellipses of each group. Groups are A, B, C ... And each ellipses of a group is denoted in the "rep" column.

I thought I might be able to do this using dplyr, but I'm having trouble because I am new to dplyr. I found on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101065/finding-the-parts-of-the-ellipse-from-my-data-in-r) how to calculate eccentricity from points of an ellipse. The steps are: calculate the centroids of the ellipse, find the semi-major and semi-minor axis, and then compute the eccentricity.

I understand how to group_by, but I am not sure how to work up the summarise part to go through the multi-step calculation. Here is what should be calculating the centroids.

```
ellipse_df <- read.csv("~/Desktop/ellipses.csv")
ellipse_df %>%
group_by(group, rep) %>%
summarise(

mean(iso1),mean(iso2))
```

Obviously this is not much. I'd like to have the output keep the grouping of the data, so I get 100 values for eccentricity for each group.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `dplyr::do` might be useful

Comment: Thanks, I was able to work it out with another function based on the covariance matrices that were used to make the ellipse points to begin with. https://github.com/AndrewLJackson/SIBER/blob/master/R/sigmaSEA.R